# Algorithm - Fomula Reading

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to find out what is the meaning of these two following lines

N + M log N
(M + N) lg* N

[image]

Can someone suggest me what is the meaning and where to learn to read this ? Thanks.

**Updated content**

For example, we will use 10 integers and 7 times for union operation. 
 Meaning, N = 10 and M = 7. 
 **Quick-find** 
 MN = 7 * 10 = 70 times 
 **Quick-union**
 MN = 7 * 10 = 70 times 
**Weighted QU**
 N + M log N = 10 + 7 log 10 = ??? 
**Path compression**
 N + M log N = 10 + 7 log 10 = ??? 
**Weighted + path**
 (M + N) lg* N = (7 + 10) lg* 10 = ???

Comment: First thing you should do is break the line down into its constituent parts. Which parts are you confused by? M, N, log, MlogN?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what is the meaning of log N and and Lg * N from these two formulas.

Comment: check this link out http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~dg/l1.html and look for "Weighted Quick-Union with Path Compression".  lg* is the iterated logarithm function. It refers to the number of times that the logartithm function must be iterated until the resulting number is less than 1

Comment: Thanks @SandiaDeDia but pls refer my understanding and could u pls suggest what will be the output ?    For example, we will use 10 integers and 7 times for union operation. Meaning, N = 10 and M = 7.  
**Quick-find**  
MN = 7 * 10 = 70 times    

**Quick-union**  
MN = 7 * 10 = 70 times    

**Weighted QU**  
N + M log N = 10 + 7 log 10 = ???    

**Path compression**  
N + M log N = 10 + 7 log 10 = ???    

**Weighted + path**  
(M + N) lg* N = (7 + 10) lg* 10 = ???

Comment: do you know what the [logarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) is?

Comment: log and lg are logarithms. lg is base 2, log is usually base 10 or base e.

Comment: @sinanspd sorry, I am not very familiar about logarithm function. I know basic only, what I understand is only like this (referred from Wiki):

In the simplest case, the logarithm counts the number of occurrences of the same factor in repeated multiplication; e.g., since 1000 = 10 × 10 × 10 = 103, the "logarithm base 10" of 1000 is 3, or log10(1000) = 3.

Comment: @newbee yes that is correct and should be enough to understand this. It is important to note that, when doing complexity analysis, the base of the logarithm **doesn't matter** because they are all related by a constant factor. You can assume it is 2, 10, e, 8, 11. Doesn't matter.

Comment: You probably know it, but they are talking about complexity of the algorithm, it roughly tells you the amount of times a certain logic will have to be executed to solve the algorithm based on the size of the input data N,M. Log is logartithm as you already know. log* =  number of times that the logartithm function must be iterated until the resulting number is less than 1. For example, log*(1000)=2 because log(log(1000))=0.47 which is lower than 1.